# Spark-scala how to work with HDFS directory partition

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

To reduce process time I partitioned my data by dates so that I use only required date data (not complete table).So now in HDFS my tables are stored like below

```
src_tbl //main dir                             trg_tbl
   2016-01-01 //sub dir                        2015-12-30
   2016-01-02                                  2015-12-31  
   2016-01-03                                  2016-01-01
                                               2016-01-03
```

Now I want to select `min(date) from src_tbl` which will be  `2016-01-01`
and from `trg_tb`l I want to use data in >= 2016-01-01`(src_tbl min(date)) directories which will be`2016-01-01 and 2016-01-03 data`

How can select required partitions or date folder from hdfs using Spark-scala ? After completing process I need to overwrite same date directories too.

**Details about process:**
I want to choose correct window of data (as all other date data in not required) from source and target table..then I want to do join -> lead / lag -> union -> write.

Answer (score 2):

Spark SQL (including the DataFrame/set api's) is kind of funny in the way it handles partitioned tables wrt retaining the existing partitioning info from one transformation/stage to the next.

For the initial loading Spark SQL tends to do a good job on understanding how to retain the underlying partitioning information - *if* that information were available in the form of the `hive metastore metadata` for the table.

So .. are these `hive` tables?

If so - so far so good - **you should see the data loaded partition by partition according to the `hive` partitions**.

> Will the DataFrame/Dataset *remember* this nice partitioning already
>   set up?

Now things get a bit more tricky.  The answer depends on whether a `shuffle` were required or not.

In your case - a simple `filter` operation - there should not be any need. So once again - **you should see the original partitioning preserved** and thus good performance.  Please verify that the partitioning were indeed retained.

I will mention that if any `aggregate` functions were invoked then you can be assured your partitioning would be lost.  Spark SQL will in that case use a `HashPartitioner` -inducing a full shuffle.

**Update** The OP provided more details here: there is `lead/lag` and `join` involved.  Then he is well advised - from the strictly *performance* perspective - to avoid the Spark SQL and do the operations manually.

To the OP: the only thing I can suggest at this point is to check

```
preservesPartitioning=true
```

were set in your RDD operations.  But I am not even sure that capability were exposed by Spark for the `lag/lead`: please check.

Comment: Hi @javadba..are you suggesting me to create hive table with dynamic partitions..and select required data using hive context query ? earlier I was using hivecontext to filter data but my process time is very high (10 min).For me total data size is 30 gb.In my process I need to do join-> lead/leg -> union->write..I am new to Spark..sorry if my few approaches are naive.

Comment: @user2895589  Your OP did not mention the `lead/lag` and `join`.  Those *do* change the situation: as mentioned in my answer if you do any `aggregate` functions then shuffle will be required: and Spark SQL will be slow.   It sounds like you were already doing things pretty close to correctly. I will update my answer.